# How to pass data from one UIViewController to another one through UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom a UIView which is in the form of a card. Now I have placed a tap gesture recognizer on it so that when my user clicks on it, it will move to the selected view controller. I have been able to achieve that and it is working well. Now my problem is I want to pass data through this action so that the new view controller can access the data. `prepareSegue` is not working. Below is my code:

```
//Function to go to plans view controller
@objc func goToPlans(_sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let moveTo = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChosenOfferViewController")
    present(moveTo!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//Function to add gestures to the card
func addGesturesToCards() {
    let planRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.goToPlans))
    planCard.addGestureRecognizer(planRec)
}
```

Comment: Why to pass data through the GestureRecognizer tap, your are calling method [goToPlans] in the same class, so your data will be there in the class itself, so in the [goToPlans] method only you can access the data and pass to other controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Just cast your View Controller as your custom class and then pass your data in this way

```
guard let moveTo = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChosenOfferViewController") as? ChosenOfferViewController else { return }
moveTo.someProperty = yourData
present(moveTo, animated: true, completion: nil)
```